# Google Maps embedded - set max zoom level

Tags: google-maps, embed

If I have an embedded Google Map

```
$("#map_frame").attr("src", "https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1Sdu3m4-YMx_Kc0gWshTNQQgSFys&z=2&ll=44.013922, -88.342259");
```

Is is possible to set a maximum zoom level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, google maps api doesn't offer that.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that might be the case but just wanted to confirm. Couldn't find it mentioned anywhere.